# Sign of square root of a real number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

May we write $\sqrt{x^2}=\pm x$.

Is  $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{(\pm x)^2}=\pm{x}$ true ?
 But we write $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=x$

What is the actual logic?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265043/square-root-principle-value-convention and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value#Square_root

Comment: [Question with related answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677123/values-of-square-roots)

Comment: This is an innocent question; why the downvotes?

Comment: Normally, $\pm$ is a kind of shorthand, whenever you see it, be wary of what it really means. In $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm x$, the meaning is "this statement is true for one of: $+$,$-$". But in $\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{(\pm x)^2}$, it means "this statement is true for both $+$ and $-$". So this is a very dangerous symbol! (Furthermore, your last equation is wrong, because $|x| \ne x$ in general.)

Answer (score 2):

You are confused because there are two notions at play here which the standard treatment of the square root obfuscates: functions and solutions of equations.

The right way to think about the square root is as a *function*: given any positive number $a$, the square root function returns the square root $\sqrt a$ (I should technically write"nonnegative" instead of "positive," but I wanted to shoot for clarity over pedantry). And what is $\sqrt a$? The unique *positive* solution to the equation $x^2=a$. I can't emphasize the "positive" part of that definition enough. It would not make any sense to define the square root to be *the* solution to the equation $x^2=a$ since in general that equation has two solutions: for instance, the equation $x^2=4$ has the two solutions $x=2$ and $x=-2$. If we defined the square root of $2$ to be *the* solution to the equation $x^2=4$, we would not know what to do when it came time to actually compute $\sqrt4$ since we would have to choose between $2$ and $-2$. Mathematicians chose $\sqrt a$ to mean the positive solution to the equation $x^2=a$, but they could just as well have chosen it to mean the negative solution (although that would have been unpopular for aesthetic reasons).

My response is a little more rambling than I intended. Does that clear up the matter?

Answer (score 0):

The square root is like a function. The function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}$ exists, but the function $f(x)=\pm \sqrt{x^2}$ does *not*. By convention, we define $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, but logically $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ as well.

Think of it like a traffic light. We *define* the red light to mean "stop", and the green light to mean "go". But *logically*, it could be the other way around. But if you think the green light means "stop", people are going to take you for a fool. Same with the whole $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ thing.

If you want an explanation from a mathematical point of view, continue reading. The function $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is the inverse of the function $f(x)=x^2$. But, we must restrict the domain to $x \ge 0$ in order for $f(x)$ to have an inverse. If the domain was $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ would not pass the horizontal line test.